# NodeJS & Express connect External API - Any useful tool, to manage the data received?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, external

I'm connecting to an external API on my backend.

- Data flow :      **External API -> My backend -> Client side**

I know that exists modules like **request** or **http** that helps this process.

But, When I receive the data from External API, I need to modify it and add some information. After I'll send this "modified data" to the Client side.

I am searching a tool similar to BackBone Collections **on the backend** to help me.  **BB Collections** have awesome functions like fetch/sort/each.

Every time I google only I found frameworks like BackBone on the client side not on the server side.

**Edit 1**

Tool would have to help me iterating over array (received from external API) or accessing to item with specific attr given.

---

**Solved**

After studying both options (Lodash and Unirest), finally I decided to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) combined with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Answer (score 2):

Try [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) to handle arrays in server side.

Answer (score 1):

```
var unirest = require('unirest');

app.get('/api', function(req, res){
  unirest.get('http://localhost:3000/getlist')
  .header('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end(function (response) {
    response.body.forEach(function(item){
      //handle item

    });
    res.send();
  });
});
```

Maybe [Unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html)?

Comment: Hi @J.D.
First of all thanks for the answer. My problem is that I need a tool, for example,  that helps me to iterate over array received from external API or access to sepecific item in this array.

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer so try if it helps now.